# docker-compose Couldn't find env file: path\variables.env

Tags: docker-compose, environment-variables

This is my first time using environment variables in docker-compose.
When I run the docker-compose up command I get the error:
`docker-compose Couldn't find env file: ${path}\variables.env`
Hereinafter **"path"** is the path to the project in Windows.
Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  geo:
    build:
      context: .
    image:geo_image
    container_name: geo
    ports:
     - "3003:3003"
    volumes:
      - ${path}:/var/geo/data
      - /app/node_modules
      - ${path}:/app
    env_file: variables.env
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: geonw
```

The **variables.env** file is located at the root of the project.
Without **variables.env** everything works fine.
Tell me, please, what is the error?
I tried giving the full path to the file, but that didn't work either.
I also carefully checked the correct name of the file **variables.env**, there is no error there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but it was just my stupid mistake and inattention. I created a **variables.env** file at a level higher than the directory with the **docker-compose.yml** file.
2 hours wasted...
Answer: The **variables.env** and **docker-compose.yml** files must be in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this should work.. also try with \ slash `.\variables.env`

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  geo:
    build:
      context: .
    image:geo_image
    container_name: geo
    ports:
     - "3003:3003"
    volumes:
      - ${path}:/var/geo/data
      - /app/node_modules
      - ${path}:/app
    env_file:
     - ./variables.env
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: geonw
```